# Passing a multidimesional array to another activity

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to pass a multidimensional array to another activity. This is how I want to be able to do it:

```
int[,,] aMultidimensionalArray = new int[a,b,c];
Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(outputActivity));
intent.PutExtra("array", aMultidimensionalArray);

StartActivity(intent);
```

However the compiler is saying that the `aMultidimesionalArray` is not serialisable. This led me to having to use `int[][][]` to declare the array which then leads to a whole host of other issues down the rest of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [Json.NET component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net) to serialize the array
Here is a simple example to serialize and deserialize an array

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

void PersonToJsonToPersonExample ()
{
    var person = new Person { Name = "Bob", Birthday = new DateTime (1987, 2, 2) };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (person);
    Console.WriteLine ("JSON representation of person: {0}", json);
    var person2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person> (json);
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1}", person2.Name, person2.Birthday);
}
```

You can also use The Application class to store objects globally and retrieve them:

```
using Android.Runtime;

namespace SomeName
{
[Application]
public class App : Application
{
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public App (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();

        Name = "";
    }
}
}
```

And you can access the data with:

```
App application = (App)Application.Context;
application.Name = "something";
```

I choose to do this on the `Application` calss because this class is called on the App startup so you don't have to initiate it manually.
Keep in mind that variables which are scoped to the `Application` have their lifetime scoped to the application by extension.
This class will be Garbage Collected if the Android feels it is necessary so you have to modify the code to include this case also.
You can use `SharedPreferences` or a `Database` to save your variables in case they get deleted and retrieve them from the App class for faster results.

Don't be overly wasteful in how you use this approach though, as attaching too much information on this class it can lead to a degradation in performance. Only add information that you know will be needed by different parts of the application, and where the cost of retrieving that information exceeds the cost of storing it as an application variable.

Investigate which information you need to hold as application wide state, and what information can simply be retrieved straight from your database. There are cost implications for both and you need to ensure you get the balance right.

And don't forget to release resources as needed on `OnStop` and `OnDestroy`.

Comment: This is a simpler way that I thought would be possible and has forced me to learn about json so thanks!

Comment: So I'm using the starter version of xamarin which means that I have the size limit and the json.net component puts me over the limit. Is there any way to get around it? I was looking into a shared dll but I couldn't find any.

Comment: yes i have update the answer with a way to store globally data on the application, in that way you dont have to pass the data to the activity, you just set the value before the initiation of the next activity and retrieve the value on OnResume or something.

Comment: OK thanks. Although I'm testing using the `System.Runtime.Serialisation.Json` to serialise the array, your idea would probably reduce the processing overhead

Comment: i had always found a better solution in my apps to make the App in a logic that all the data can be globally defined and accessed that way, i never really like intents. you can to make code for sending, retrieving etc, why to do that if you can define them globally

Comment: That does seem like a better way although that could lead to memory overheads on really massive objects

Comment: yes you should consider how to clear the memory on OnStop or OnDestroy but this would be a good idea too to do it if you were sending the data with intent. You always have to keep in mind memory usage

Comment: also keep in mind that the student edition of Xamarin has a very low price or is free now. If there is a college member on your team you should consider that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92303/discussion-between-cjen1-and-cdrosos).